# ANSI Color Codes in VIM

Tags: vim, ansi-escape, ansi-colors, color-codes

I have a script that generates a log file with ANSI color codes in them like so:

```
[2012-05-14 18:00:02] ^[[0mINF: -- Starting update script --^[[0m
[2012-05-14 18:00:29] ^[[91mERR: Improper date, entry being ignored.^[[0m
```

Is there any way to get Vim to understand these color codes?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/358409/how-can-i-tell-vim-to-show-ansi-escape-codes-properly

Comment: See the answer at https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20496/3324: *“If you have a sufficiently modern vim that has the +terminal feature, you can do `:term cat somefile` and you'll get a buffer with all the terminal codes interpreted.

This might work better on large files than e.g. Colorizer, which made my vim unusably slow when I let it loose on a 6000-line file.”*

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use Charles Campbell's (Dr Chip) AnsiEsc plugin:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302

Before:

[image: before]

`:AnsiEsc<CR>`

[image: after]

Comment: I had to change `91m` and `93m` to `31m` and `33m`, respectively, but it worked beautifully otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Change them where? (the vba file is pretty hairy...) I'm still getting some escape sequences instead of colors...

Comment: Nevermind. The colours are applied, but I think I need to recompile vim with the 'conceal' feature to hide the escape sequences.

Comment: The link [does not seem to be working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8241/311650). Is there a chance for a script to be included in the answer?

Comment: could not get this to work with vim 7.4  -- any chance there is another solution?

Comment: The [Vim.org scripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) are all [mirrored on github](https://github.com/vim-scripts).  This script would be https://github.com/vim-scripts/AnsiEsc.vim  Both sites have code that is 6y old, so your source doesn't matter as much, but the Vim.org version lets you install it as a vimball (.vba.gz), which is easier.  This works for me on Vim 8.0.

Comment: There is a newer fork of Charles Campbell's (Dr Chip) AnsiEsc by Alex Efros: [Improved AnsiEsc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4979) ([github](https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-AnsiEsc)).

Comment: Default `vim` on macOS is not compiled with `conceal` feature, you need to install complete `vim` with `brew install vim`

Answer (score 64):

I'm not sure about vim, but if you're just viewing a log file (ie you don't need to be able to edit) you could use less:

```
less -R
```

Comment: this is so useful that no one has complained about the fact that it very much doesn't answer the question as asked 

Answer (score 7):

`AnsiEsc` works with basic ANSI color codes, but not other codes.
The problem is that 
there are *lots* of [ANSI_escape_code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) s
beyond the basic `\033[31m red \033[0m`;
what is `AnsiEsc`, what is any program, to do with `\033[... unrecognized` ?
It seems that `AnsiEsc` just leaves such alone, but differently in Vim and mvim.

Better doc on `AnsiEsc` would be welcome;
links to a small ANSI escape code parser in python would be welcome.

A test case for colored output from gnu ls and grep, with `TERM xterm-256color`
and macosx Terminal version 2.3:

```
#!/bin/bash
# test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors from gnu ls and grep

mkdir bluedir  2> /dev/null
ls -d --color=always  bluedir  > ls.out

echo red-hot | grep --color=always  red  > grep.out

od -c ls.out
# 0000000  033   [   0   m 033   [   3   4   m   b   l   u   e   d   i   r
# 0000020  033   [   0   m  \n                                            
# Vim 7.3 :AnsiEsc "bluedir" blue, \033[0m as is
# mvim 8.0 :AnsiEsc "bluedir" works

od -c grep.out
# 0000000  033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   r   e   d 033   [
# 0000020    m 033   [   K   -   h   o   t  \n                            
# both Vim and mvim display as is
```

See also the lovely bash script [colors256](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037?highlight=(color)) .

Comment: THIS! I read your comment and kept seeing that my 'basic' codes weren't being translated by the script. The problem I had was I considering the 3x and the 9x codes as basic (regular & bright).  AnsiEsc ONLY deals with the 3x codes.

Answer (score 6):

Since the link in the accepted answer doesn't appear to be working, I found this link: https://github.com/vim-scripts/AnsiEsc.vim

Comment: New forked version: https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-AnsiEsc