# vim displaying ^[[32m while redirecting output to file using ssh from iterm

Tags: vim, ssh, ubuntu-16.04, iterm2

I am sshing from iTerm2 to an Ubuntu machine.
I am using ns3 through waf and redirecting my output to a log file using the below command:

```
mpirun -n 16 ./waf --run test > log.out 2>&1
```

The log file that gets generated has output like below:

```
^[[32mWaf: Entering directory `/home/workspace/ns-allinone-3.25/ns-3.25/build/optimized'^[[0m
^[[32mWaf: Entering directory `/home/workspace/ns-allinone-3.25/ns-3.25/build/optimized'^[[0m
```

I am unable to understand why the extra characters are being added in the file.
When I use `less` to view the contents, I see the output perfectly fine.
What should I do to not see the extra in `vim`.

Comment: Those look like ASCII color codes. Check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592852/3101082

Comment: The above does not seem to be working. To add I am using solarized light theme on iTerm2. Can that be a cause?

Comment: Could you take a look at the man page of your tool to see if it has a `--color` param or similar?

Answer (score 0):

If your vim `echo has('conceal')` return `1`, try this simple solution to hide `^[[32m`

```
syntax match Special /^[\[32m/ conceal
```

Note: you'd better copy `^[` from the log file for it's actually a `Ctrl-[`