# vim as pager for journalctl

Tags: linux, vim, pager

I would like to use vim as pager for journalctl. Is it possible and how?

I am on fedora, when I naively open journalctl, it is a default pager, I am unable to go to last line quickly.
I have tried `PAGER="vim -" journalctl` as found on a forum without any change.

Using `export SYSTEMD_PAGER=cat` effectively use cat as pager, but I have been unable to use `export SYSTEMD_PAGER=vim`.

How would you read your journal within vim?

Comment: I wouldn't. Vim is a text editor.

Comment: @Pierre Vittet - You did not tell the result of having _tried `PAGER="vim -" journalctl`_. Also you did not tell why you _have been unable to use `export SYSTEMD_PAGER=vim.`_

Comment: The result for both command was that journalctl was called using the default pager instead of using vim as pager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try piping to `vim`:

```sh
journalctl -b | vim -
```

### Use Priorities to Filter Output

Typically, `journalctl` will color code log entries depending on whether they are errors, warnings, info, etc. These colors correspond to *priorities*. This color coding will not be present in the logs piped to `vim`.

A simple way to search for logs with a particular priority is to use the journalctl option `-p`:

```sh
journalctl -b -p 3 | vim -
```

where `3` corresponds to errors.

You can use this table to determine which priority to use.

| Priority | Log Level |
| --- | --- |
| emerg | 0 |
| alert | 1 |
| crit | 2 |
| err | 3 |
| warning | 4 |
| notice | 5 |
| info | 6 |
| debug | 7 |

See the `--priority=` option in the journalctl manual page for more information.

### Use Color Coding in Vim

If you still want to see color coded logs in Vim, that is possible.

The underlying basis for this are ANSI escape codes. It is not necessary to know anything about ANSI escape codes.

But, to get color to work, we need to solve two problems:

1. Instruct journalctl to output ANSI escape codes.
2. Format ANSI escape codes in Vim.

#### Instruct journalctl to output ANSI escape codes

The manual page for journalctl mentions an environment variable which will produce the desired output.

Set the `SYSTEMD_COLORS` environment variable to `true` in your shell:

```sh
export SYSTEMD_COLORS=true
```

You can make this variable permanent by adding it to your `~/.bashrc`

Now, when you run `journalctl`, you will notice ANSI escape codes in `vim`:

```sh
journalctl -b -p 4 | vim -
```

Example of ANSI escape code:

> ^[[0;1;38;5;185m

Or, if output to the shell, logs will be color coded there:

```sh
journalctl -b -p 4 -n 10 --no-pager
```

#### Format ANSI escape codes in Vim

Vim requires a plugin to interpret ANSI escape codes. More information can be found in the links below.

The file you need can be found [here](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/AnsiEsc.vba.gz) (direct).

From a shell, open the downloaded file with `vim`:

```sh
vim AnsiEsc.vba.gz
```

Then, within `vim`, install the plugin:

```
:so %
```

You can quit `vim` after installing the plugin:

```
:q
```

#### Color Example

After setting the environment variable and installing the plugin, try viewing color coded logs.

From the shell, pipe color coded logs to `vim`:

```sh
journalctl -b -p 4 | vim -
```

From `vim`, activate the plugin to format the logs:

```
:AnsiEsc
```

Now you should see color coded systemd logs in vim.

Regards,

### References

[journalctl | Arch manual pages](https://man.archlinux.org/man/journalctl.1)

[ANSI escape code | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

[env, setenv, & export | Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368944/what-is-the-difference-between-env-setenv-export-and-when-to-use)

[bash: true or false | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-can-i-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-a-shell-script)

[Permanently Setting Environmental Variables | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-linux#implementing-environmental-variables)

[Can colorized output be captured via shell redirect? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515208/can-colorized-output-be-captured-via-shell-redirect/3515392#3515392)

[ANSI Color Codes in VIM | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592715/ansi-color-codes-in-vim)

[Introduction to Plugins | Vim Online Help](https://vimhelp.org/usr_05.txt.html#05.6)

[AnsiEsc Plugin | vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) (Outdated `AnsiEsc.vba.gz`)

[AnsiEsc | Dr Chip's Vim Page](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#ANSIESC) (Find the latest `AnsiEsc.vba.gz` here.)

[AnsiEsc Manual | Dr Chip's Vim Page](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/doc/AnsiEsc.txt.html)

[vimball | vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1502)

[:so | Vim Online Help](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Aso)

[% | Vim Online Help](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%7Baddress%7D)